# UITableView - Automatic Load Next 25... when nearing bottom

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios

Instead of the normal tap "Load Next 25..." at the bottom of a UITableView, I want the same loadNext: method to be called automatically as the user scrolls near to the bottom, so when the bottom is actually reached, the results will either already be there or a ActivitySpinner holding their place.

Does anybody know of an example that does this? I'd like to keep the behaviour consistent with any other apps that use a similar feature (similar to the "Pull down to refresh" behaviour we are seeing in many apps now).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in my app Think Messenger is add an extra row at the bottom of the table with an activity indicator. In my data source, whenever that cell is requested, I start downloading the next page of data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that goes step-by-step on how to do the 'pull to refresh' scheme.  You can certainly repurpose it do it for the footer.

[How to make a Pull-To-Reload TableView](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/12/how-to-make-a-pull-to-reload-tableview-just-like-tweetie-2/)

Comment: This question is about loading more cells at the bottom and not refreshing the table on a pull down. The concept is different, because you want to start downloading content automatically even before reaching bottom.